# Why does PHP's composer require command hang?

Tags: command-line, php, composer, php-cli

Note: I know this is a PHP question, but - and I could be wrong here - but I think the problem may only exist with PHP, composer on ubuntu.

Anyway, almost every tutorial, including composer itself say run the composer `require` command to install a package, e.g.

```
composer require robmorgan/phinx
```

However, for me, on Ubuntu , all this ever does is hang the terminal, until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> of of the terminal.
How can I get this command to work?

Comment: Can you trace the calls with `strace -f composer require robmorgan/phinx`

Comment: @heemayl ah, great idea, Ive run your `strace` command. the output is that it sits there in a polling loop. it seems to be waiting for some kind of network or remote response

Comment: it seems to pull down data bit by bit. I think the bottleneck must be with packagist's server - its probably getting hammered pretty hard

Comment: hmmmm...now, as you have found the potential reason, you can check the address directly to make sure of things...

Comment: @heemayl can you clarify address? you mean the remote url?

Comment: Yes, check the `connect()` and `sendto()` calls as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59429/discussion-between-the-velour-fog-and-heemayl).

Answer (score 6):

To see why composer hangs, use the `-vvv` argument to make the output more `v`erbose.

`composer -vvv require robmorgan/phinx`